# Why Select Element is of type DispHTMLWndSelectElement but not HTMLSelectElement in IE9?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-9, prototypejs

I'm trying to make a simple java script page developed for IE8 compatible with IE9 and higher. The select tag is giving "TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'getValue'" when i try to use the getValue() method of prototype. This page is working fine in all versions of IE **except in IE9 for few County Users who are not having ADMIN rights.**

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
     <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript" SRC="prototype.js"></SCRIPT>
   </head>
   <body style="width:500px">
   <form id="example" action="#" onsubmit="return false">
     <div id="container">
       <select size="7" style="width:auto;" name="commonRTSelect" id="commonRTSelect" multiple>
       <option value="volvo" selected>Volvo</option>
       <option value="saab" selected>Saab</option>
       <option value="mercedes" selected>Mercedes</option>
       <option value="audi">Audi</option>
       </select>
      <input type="text" style="width:auto;"  name="fname" id="fname" value="madhu">  
      <br>
   </div>
  </form>
  <input type="button" value="Toggle" onclick="showResult();"/>

<script>

function showResult() {
    var elems = $('container').select('input','select','textarea');
    elems.each( function(e){
        if(e instanceof HTMLElement) {
            alert("Yes.."+e.name+"  is an instance of HTMLElement");
        }
        else {
            alert("No "+e.name+" is not an instance of HTMLElement. it is " + e);
        }
    });

    try{
        alert("Dropdown Value>> " + $('commonRTSelect').getValue());
    }
    catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I was debugging this issue, i found that the select tag is of type DispHTMLWndSelectElement. Not able to attach screenshots here..

Comment: just use "commonRTSelect.value", it works everywhere. or, if you want >1, commonRTSelect.querySelectorAll(":checked")

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But why is it failing only in the County user login? The page is working fine in the Administrator login in the same machine on the same IE9 browser. What could actually cause such errors? why the MSHTML interop is changing the way it works returning such object to me only in non-admin login?

Comment: Can someone plz help?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of,

```
$('commonRTSelect').getValue()
```

...please try,

```
$F('commonRTSelect')
```

Internally they should be calling the same function, which is actually [checking the element's tag name](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/d9411e5/src/prototype/dom/form.js#L581).  The problem here is `DispHTMLWndSelectElement` hasn't inherited the `getValue()` function from `HTMLSelectElement` so the solution is to not call the instance method.

As to why IE decides to break compatibility, *again*, is anyone's guess.  Perhaps it detected a character that isn't in the document's charset and fell back to another rendering mode.  It would be hard to tell without comparing both page sources and a ouigii board.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but unfortunately, it didn't work.. I'm still seeing the same error. To your point, if the document has a character that isn't in the UTF-8 Charset, How is it working in the same machine if I log in as Admin?

Comment: I don't actually think the charset has anything to do with it, that was an example of a (bad) guess.  I could not find an explanation of `DispHTMLWndSelectElement`, the top hit for it is this page, I think something more significant is going on with your computer for it to break like that.